# how to show form submitted in php when python code runs in background

Tags: javascript, php, python, html

I am working on a web server where user submits some information/inputs in a html form. On clicking the submit button the background php code initiates a python code for analysis. Python code takes long time. Following code shows 'form submitted' message when python code finishes. I do not want the user to wait until the python code finishes. I want to show user the 'form submitted' message when the submit button is clicked and python code will keep on running in the server. 
html

```
<form name="input" action='input.php'  method="post">
<input type="text" name="num1" id="num1" size="4">
<input type="text" name="num2" id="num2" size="4">
<input type="submit" name = "submit" value="Submit" class="submit"/>
</form>
```

php

```
echo ("Form submitted");
$num1=$_POST["num1"];
$num2=$_POST["num2"];
$makeinfo= shell_exec('python mypycode.py');
```

I already searched in this site and did not find any useful post.
Please comment/reply/vote only if it is useful to solve this issue.

Comment: send an ajax request but don't wait for the response if the user does not need to know the result or your page no longer needs to perform any tasks with the request

Comment: @RamRaider I also think so. Can you show example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate the comment a very simple ajax request sent, in this case to the same page but would be to `input.php`, which takes a while to process data ( hence the `sleep` ) ~ the request is sent but no callback is used or waits for the response - look in the network tab of the console

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        /* to emulate input.php processing request using python */
        ob_clean();
        sleep(20);
        exit( json_encode( $_POST ) );
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>ajax - send and forget</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form name='input' action='<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>'>
            <input type='text' name='num1' size='4'>
            <input type='text' name='num2' size='4'>
            <input type='submit' value='Submit' class='submit' />
            <div id='msg'></div>
        </form>

        <script>
            const ajax=function( url, query ){
                let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
                    xhr.send( query );
            }

            document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click',e=>{
                e.preventDefault();
                ajax( e.target.parentNode.action, new FormData( e.target.parentNode ) );
                document.getElementById('msg').innerText='Request sent... Game Over';
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

The above is NOT intended to be the code you use - merely to illustrate the use of a send and forget type ajax request. The form `ACTION` attribute is used in the ajax call - and as I don't have a file called `input.php` I showed the request to the same page. Your actual `input.php` will NOT have the `sleep` function call - perhaps this might be of more use to you... it really is very basic ~ adapt this to your webpage and form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>ajax - send and forget</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form name='input' action='input.php'>
            <input type='text' name='num1' size='4'>
            <input type='text' name='num2' size='4'>
            <input type='submit' value='Submit' class='submit' />
            <div id='msg'></div>
        </form>

        <script>
            const ajax=function( url, query ){
                let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
                    xhr.send( query );
            }

            document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click',e=>{
                e.preventDefault();
                ajax( e.target.parentNode.action, new FormData( e.target.parentNode ) );
                document.getElementById('msg').innerText='Request sent... Game Over';
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi RamRaider, Thanks for your answer but I do not understand it. It is not calling 'input.php' and hence not executing python code. Also, it seems sleep time is given to finish the python code. But the time taken by python code varies. This time depends on user's input.